# Flutter: compare current date with date received from api

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an app that receives some data from a api and i want to compare them, but dont know how to do it.

The date that comes from the api is in a different template, plus its a string, so i cant compare.

I want to show a error message if the received date is older than  current date.

Here's how the api date comes (i have printed on console):

```
I/flutter ( 5190): 2004-08-26T01:00:00.000Z
```

And here is the DateTime.now on flutter:

```
I/flutter ( 5190): 2021-02-19 12:25:16.638505
```

Is there a way to compare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the date from the `api` to the `Datetime`method(utc) in flutter and then you can compare.for example

```
String apidatetime= '2004-08-26T01:00:00.000Z';
DateTime.parse(apidatetime).isAtSameMomentAs(DateTimenow)
```

[also check this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html)

Comment: I have received the date on a variable and then "if (DateTime.now().isBefore(DateTime.parse(apidatetime))" and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the API date to a DateTime type and then compare the DateTimes like this:

```
DateTime.now().isAfter(apiDate)
DateTime.now().isBefore(apiDate)
DateTime.now().isAtSameMomentAs(apiDate)
```

Each of this lines will return a bool.

If te API date comes as Timestamp, you can convert it like this:

```
apiDate = apiTimestamp.toDate()
```